# Variation to the Set-Covering Prob (Maybe an Activity Selection Prob)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Everyday from 9am to 5pm, I am supposed to have at least one person at the factory supervising the workers and make sure that nothing goes wrong.

There are currently *n* applicants to the job, and each of them can work from time *si* to time *ci*, *i* = 1, 2, ..., *n*.

My goal is to minimize the time that more than two people are keeping watch of the workers at the same time.

(The applicants' available working hours are able to cover the time period from 9am to 5pm.)

I have proved that at most two people are needed for any instant of time to fulfill my needs, but how should I get from here to the final solution?

Finding the time periods where only one person is available for the job and keeping them is my first step, but finding the next step is what troubles me... .

The algorithm must run in polynomial-time.

Any hints(a certain type of data structure maybe?) or references are welcome. Many thanks.

Comment: It is looking like variant of Activity Selection Algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with dynamic programming by solving the sub-problem:

> What is the minimum overlap time given that applicant i is the last worker and we have covered all times from start of day up to ci?

Call this value of the minimum overlap time cost(i).

You can compute the value of cost(i) by considering cases:

1. If si is equal to the start of day, then cost(i) = 0 (no overlap is required)
2. Otherwise, consider all previous applicants j.  Set cost(i) to the minimum of cost(j)+overlap between i and j.  Also set prev(i) to the value of j that attains the minimum.

Then the answer to your problem is given by the minimum of cost(k) for all values of k where ck is equal to the end of the day.  You can work out the correct choice of people by backtracking using the values of prev.

This gives an O(n^2) algorithm.